# Format all Strings from specific Class with Annotation inside a Method

Tags: java, annotations, format

Let's say, I have the following method:

```
public void anyMethod(User user){
    user.sendMessage(Messages.sendUsernameNotFound());
}
```

The `Messages.sendUsernameNotFound()` method is a `static` method which returns just a `String`.

Let's say I want to format all the Strings from the class 'Messages', is it possible to do it with an annotation?

e.g.:

```
@FormatMessage
public void anyMethod(User user){
    user.sendMessage(Messages.sendUsernameNotFound());
}
```

I've never worked before with custom annotations.

The reason why I am asking is that I have a lot of methods which are using the Messages Class, so I was wondering if it would be simple to do with annotations.

Sure I can use `Utilz.formatMessage(Messages.sendUsernameNotFound());` but to do it in all the methods it would be messy.

Thank you for your help and advise!

Comment: rename the existing `Messages.sendUsernameNotFound()` to `Messages.sendUsernameNotFoundFormatted()`, recreate `Messages.sendUsernameNotFound()` by copy/paste of the renamed method, use `Utilz.formatMessage` in `Messages.sendUsernameNotFoundFormatted()`. You should also consider not using static access.

Comment: First of all: why does a function called sendXXX return a String? Second: why can't this function return a formatted string?

Comment: Technically, you can do that. but keep in mind that annotations are expensive - they use reflection which is not ideal in terms of performance. Sounds to me that annotation here is an overkill and redundant

Comment: Everytime I hear "I want to have this kind of behavior in a lot of methods" aspects come to my mind. You could try to use AspectJ to inject the desired formatter if you want different formatters for different classes. If you don't want different formatters, though, go with @brummfondel suggestion and make Messages return the formatted string.